# Merge facebook and google user in Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, google-signin

In my app i recently added a login by mail, Facebook and google.

[image: Login Fragment]

I can login by every single method but not on same account .

I can switch Providers : Facebook-> Google on Firebase but cannot change Google -> Facebook
I must add that I dont do seperete accounts for diffrent providers, to merge them.
Could some one help me with this linking Credencials?

```
        package com.company.altasnotas.fragments.login_and_register;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
    
    
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.company.altasnotas.MainActivity;
    import com.company.altasnotas.R;
    import com.company.altasnotas.fragments.home.HomeFragment;
    import com.company.altasnotas.viewmodels.LoginFragmentViewModel;
    
    
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Objects;
    
    import com.facebook.AccessToken;
    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
    import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
    import com.facebook.FacebookException;
    
    import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
    import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInApi;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
    import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase;
    
    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
    
    
    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 120;
        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        LoginFragmentViewModel model;
        LoginButton facebookLoginButton;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
          mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
          model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LoginFragmentViewModel.class);
          EditText email_editext = view.findViewById(R.id.login_email_edittext);
          EditText password_editext = view.findViewById(R.id.login_password_edittext);
          view.findViewById(R.id.login_w_mail_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                model.login((MainActivity) requireActivity(),email_editext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim(),password_editext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim());
              }
          });
          view.findViewById(R.id.jump_to_register_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new RegisterFragment()).commit();
              }
          });
    
            // Initialize Facebook Login button
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
    
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            facebookLoginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fb_new_login_button);
            facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
            facebookLoginButton.setFragment(this);
    
    
            // Callback registration
            facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    Log.d("Dziala ", "Token: "+ token.getUserId());
                    handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                  Log.d("Facebook","Login Canceled");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d("Facebook","Login error: "+exception.toString());
                }
            });
    
    
    
    
    
    
            ImageButton fb_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.login_fb_btn);
            fb_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> facebookLoginButton.performClick());
    
    
            //Google Auth
            ImageButton google_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.login_google_btn);
    
            // Configure Google Sign In
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(), gso);
    
    
            google_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    signIn();
                }
            });
    
    
            return view;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            mainActivity.updateUI(user);
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    
        private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
            MainActivity mainActivity  = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    
            String TAG="Facebook";
            Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
    
            AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(mainActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Link Facebook success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Link Facebook fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else {
                mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(mainActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            mainActivity.updateUI(user);
                            int count = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                            }
    
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Sign Facebook success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_bottom);
                            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home_item);
                            mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                        } else {
    
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Sign Facebook fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mainActivity.updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    
    
    
        private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    try {
                        // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                        Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.w(TAG, task.getException().toString());
                }
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
        private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
            MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(mainActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"Link google succeded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                mainActivity.updateUI(user);
                                BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_bottom);
                                bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home_item);
    
                                int count = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                    mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                                }
                                mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"Link google failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    }
                });
            }else {
                mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(mainActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Sign Google  success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            mainActivity.updateUI(user);
                            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_nav_bottom);
                            //We shouldnt could go back so if i were transfering to another activity
                            // I should add finish(); at the end of code after starting another activity
                            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home_item);
    
                            int count = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                            }
                            mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Sign Google failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mainActivity.updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Also I want to add i tried a  method with GoogleApiClient but it shows me that no matter what ID i choose it's always been used by program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who had same problem :

Problem here is that Google switch providers which shouldnt happen.
Its a long time bug and they didnt fixed it.They called it a feature haha.

Thats why i spend two days on fixing this for nothing.Thanks Google